# Converting Data.txt to data.csv with awk and bash

Tags: excel, bash, csv, awk

I have a data file in the following format: `word;URL;title"name";`. 
I want to convert this data.txt to excel sheet with 3 columns with `;` as a separator.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do always add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your problem in your post with code tags, kindly do so and let us know then.

Comment: can you share the sample data

Comment: Will you ever find a semicolon in any of the quoted parts? I think the answer is to just rename the file to data.csv.

Comment: just open in Excel with that delimiter set.